# Cannot login to mymonero

Tags: mymonero

I'm having problems to login to mymonero, either with the chrome extension and the webapp. After confirming the private key, I click on the button but nothing happens. This is also the case when I try to log in using a previously created private login key.

Anyone having this problem?
I'm using google chrome 59.0.3071.86 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Ubuntu 16.04.

Thx

Comment: Have you tried using a different browser?

Answer (score 3):

I just found the problem. Turns out the application tries to connect to the API on port 8443. And I was behind a firewall. Maybe it would be good if that info was on the site. Thanks anyway